# Does puppet get the Service from init.d

Tags: service, puppet, init.d

I know that this question was maybe asked by someone else, but I couldn't find it.

I created a custom init script and would like that puppet uses it. So my question now is, does puppet service look into the init.d folder to find a init script?

Thanks for answering in advance!

Regards

Alexander

Answer (score 1):

Sort of dependent on your init system and the provider puppet uses for it, but generally if you create an init script that works puppet will find it based on the name of the script.

Example:

/etc/init.d/mycustomservice

can be puppetized via

```
  service {'mycustomservice':
    ensure => running,
  }
```